# How do I parse value as datetime?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have dates as below:

```
        date
0       Today, 12 Mar
1    Tomorrow, 13 Mar
2    Tomorrow, 13 Mar
3    Tomorrow, 13 Mar
4    Tomorrow, 13 Mar
5         14 Mar 2021
6         14 Mar 2021
7         14 Mar 2021
8         14 Mar 2021
9         15 Mar 2021
```

How do I parse it as datetime in pandas?

Answer (score 1):

Your date contains 'Today' and 'Tomorrow' which is not a valid format(if it is valid then I don't know I never worked with this type of format) of datetime so firstly replace them to 2021(if year is fixed...i.e 2021):-

```
df['date']=df['date'].str.replace('Today','2021')
df['date']=df['date'].str.replace('Tomorrow','2021')
```

Now just use `to_datetime()` method:-

```
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

Comment: 'Today' and 'Tomorrow' are *valid*, they're just not known to the parser pandas uses. And I think this is ok since it involves some kind of guessing to parse them.