# How do I correctly format datetime?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I am not able to correctly convert the date column

```
dte

                  date  Odds_Home  Odds_Draw  Odds_Away        Home_Team         Away_Team
0        Today, 12 Mar       3.82       3.35       2.10       Newcastle        Aston Villa
1     Tomorrow, 13 Mar       4.64       3.97       1.76           Leeds            Chelsea
2     Tomorrow, 13 Mar       1.90       3.49       4.54         Everton            Burnley
3     Tomorrow, 13 Mar       9.72       5.04       1.36          Fulham    Manchester City
4  2021-03-14 00:00:00       2.60       3.36       2.83         Arsenal          Tottenham
5  2021-03-14 00:00:00       1.87       3.60       4.48  Manchester Utd           West
```

:

```
    dte['date'] = dte['date'].str.replace('Today', '2021')
    dte['date'] = dte['date'].str.replace('Tomorrow', '2021')
    dte['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dte['date'])
    print(dte)
```

How do I correctly convert date column to datetime without having `NaT`?

```
        date  Odds_Home  Odds_Draw  Odds_Away        Home_Team         Away_Team
0 2021-03-12       3.82       3.35       2.10       Newcastle        Aston Villa
1 2021-03-13       4.64       3.97       1.76           Leeds            Chelsea
2 2021-03-13       1.90       3.49       4.54         Everton            Burnley
3 2021-03-13       9.72       5.04       1.36          Fulham    Manchester City
4        NaT       2.60       3.36       2.83         Arsenal          Tottenham
5        NaT       1.87       3.60       4.48  Manchester Utd           West Ham

dte['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dte['date'])
```

error I get

```
raise ParserError("Unknown string format: %s", timestr)
dateutil.parser._parser.ParserError: Unknown string format: Today, 12 Mar
```

Comment: So, did the answer to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66604186/10197418) not help you?

Comment: This one has `2021-03-14 00:00:00 2021-03-14 00:00:00 ` instead of just 14 Mar 2021
Maybe thats why datetime is not recognising it. how can I best format it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pd.to_datetime(df.date.str.replace('(Today|Tomorrow),', '2021'))
```

**Output**

```
0   2021-03-12
1   2021-03-13
2   2021-03-13
3   2021-03-13
4   2021-03-14
5   2021-03-14
```

Comment: I get this error: dateutil.parser._parser.ParserError: Unknown string format: Today, 12 Mar

Comment: @PyNoob which pandas version are you using

Comment: Pandas version 1.2.2 there is an upgrade available